# Angular Universal with .netCore Web Api integration

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, webapi

I have a .net5 WebApi that serves an Angular 12 application (created separately) as static files, I want to improve its performance with server-side rendering provided by Angular Universal, my app is published with Heroku. I can't find an approach to achieve that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I've written an article about this](https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-update-705c0ec01931) some time ago (.NET Core 3.1). However since .NET 5 the `NodeServices` have been deprecated.

Blazor as it is today, is still no option for me, so today [I created a new repository using the code required for SSR](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing). This package targets .NET 6, so you're going to have to upgrade your project too.

Edit:

There's a demo project [embedded in the repository](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/tree/master/Demo%2FDemo.Web). You should be able to simply run the database migrations

```
cd Demo/Demo.Data
dotnet ef database update
```

and run the **Demo.Web** project.

Comment: thank you Pieterjan, I've already checked your articles, can you provide a minimal project sample or update your articles, as I found the documentation confusing a bit?

Comment: I have checked your demo project, did you only follow the Angular documentation in setting up the SSR on the client-side? If there are additional steps can you highlight them, please? Still encouraging you to write an updated article with clear steps!

Comment: Hi, actually there's a sample embedded in the repository, under the [Demo/Demo.Web](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/tree/master/Demo%2FDemo.Web) folder.

Comment: And yes, the instructions are those of ng-universal. Actually `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` does everything for you. However, there are some quirks that need to be fixed. I'll check the guide

Comment: I just tried putting something together [in this link](https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-2022-version-7aaed8157976). But I did not re-execute it yet.

Comment: @Pieterjan any reason to use `nguniversal/express` instead of  this `@nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine` ? Am I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: I did try once to use `@nguniversal/aspnetcore-engine` (3 years ago) but didn't manage to get it working...